# "TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" with webdriver.chrome

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium, selenium-webdriver

```
from selenium import webdriver 

driver = webdriver.chrome("F:\\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("https://www.nvidia.in/graphics-cards/geforce/pascal/buy/")
```

Comment: What are you even asking. I don't see a single `?`

Answer (score 11):

In python, letter 'c' will be in upper case in the function chrome().

**INCORRECT**

```
import webdriver

driver = webdriver.chrome("F:\\chromedriver.exe")
```

**PROPER:**

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium

driver = webdriver.Chrome("F:\\Chromedriver.exe")
```

Comment: Please add more explanation to your answer

Comment: @Mastisa this error usually occurs because of c of "chrome" is not capital.

Answer (score 4):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium 
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

C should be capital in `webdriver.Chrome()`

Also, the path for driver is not required. The driver is already installed on the computer.

Answer (score 1):

Yor are miss spell the class name. It is not chrome(), Chrome().

`webdriver.chrome("F:\\chromedriver.exe")`

to

`webdriver.Chrome("F:\\chromedriver.exe")`

or

`webdriver.Chrome()`

Answer (score 1):

```
from selenium import webdriver
import selenium

driver = webdriver.Chrome(r"C:\Users\007\Desktop\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")

driver.get("http://www.python.org")
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 1):

**Can you do this to see if it's installed?**

`import selenium`

`print selenium.__version__`

As for the

`driver = webdriver.chrome("F:\\chromedriver.exe")`

You can just use:
`driver = webdriver.Chrome();`

**in Chrome the c has to be a capital letter.**

Answer (score 0):

first install webdriver manager and write the below code
pip install webdriver-manager

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
from selenium import webdriver

driver = webdriver.Chrome(ChromeDriverManager().install())
driver.get("desired url")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this -

```
from selenium 
import webdriver

from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service 
import Service

service_obj=Service() 
driver= webdriver.Chrome(service=service_obj) driver.get("https://www.linkedin.com/feed/?trk=")
```