# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error using ChromeDriver and Chrome and Selenium Python

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

```
from selenium import webdriver
driver=webdriver.chrome(r'C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
res=driver.get('http://www.facebook.com')
print(res)
```

When I run above program I got error i.e

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-911037a3fee4> in <module>
      1 from selenium import webdriver
----> 2 driver=webdriver.chrome(r'C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
      3 res=driver.get('http://www.facebook.com')
      4 print(res)

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["TypeError: 'module' object is not callable" with webdriver.chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51188180/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-with-webdriver-chrome)

Answer (score 0):

`driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path="the path")` should work fine
also you are doing smth strange, you are printing a function, use `driver.get('facebook...')` instead and then print smth that you define elsewise

Comment: from selenium import webdriver  
driver = webdriver.Firefox()  
driver.get('http://www.facebook.com')  
i used that code and it worked fine. you can just replace the Firefox by Chrome and insert the executable_path = xy

Answer (score 0):

This error message...

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

...implies that the **`webdriver.chrome`** is a module and hence is not **callable**.

**`selenium.webdriver.chrome.webdriver`** is one of the [Selenium](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54459701/what-is-selenium-and-what-is-webdriver/54482491#54482491) related [Python Module](https://selenium.dev/selenium/docs/api/py/py-modindex.html) and is not **callable**.

To initiate an [google-chrome](/questions/tagged/google-chrome) session through [ChromeDriver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59909654/how-does-chrome-driver-interact-with-chrome-browser/59927747#59927747) you need to replace the small `c` with capital **`C`**. So effectively your line of code will be:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(r'C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
```

Ideally, you need to pass the absolute path of the *chromedriver.exe* using the key `executable_path` as follows:

```
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\Users\DELL\Downloads\chromedriver.exe')
```

---

### References

You can find a couple of relevant discussions in:

- [How to resolve Selenium with Python: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59649959/how-to-resolve-selenium-with-python-typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable/59654170#59654170)
- [TypeError: 'module' object is not callable error with driver=webdriver(“C:\Python34\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromedriver.exe”)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51243290/typeerror-module-object-is-not-callable-error-with-driver-webdriverc-pyth/51245550#51245550)